# More than one html form in a php file

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a php and html based tool that has a form that, when submitted, outputs the data reformatted using echo commands.

I'd like to add a 2nd form to the same page that will also output using echo.

My issue is, when I submit the 2nd form the first forms output disappears.  I'd like to make it so the echo output from the first form does not go away when the 2nd form is submitted so they will both be on the screen at the same time.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Can you provide your code please. Your HTML/PHP would be most helpful in describing your problem.

Comment: From your comment below, it looks like you want to submit both forms. Not sure why you're doing that but if you must then add a hidden iframe and submit the first form to that to process so you can submit second form after. `<form target="iframe_name"`

Answer (score 2):

Only one `<form>` block in a page can be submitted at a single time. `<input>` fields defined in one form will not be submitted when the other form is submitted.

e.g.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="foo" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form>
   <input type="text" name="bar" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Clicking on submit will submit either a `foo` field, **OR** a `bar` field. Not both. If you want both fields to be submitted, then you have to either build them into a SINGLE form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

or use Javascript to copy the data from one form to another.

Comment: I dont want both to submit at the same time. When I use this utility I do the first one and then sometime later I do the 2nd, but I want the output from both to stay.  Right now when I do the 2nd one the first one disappears since the &_POST entries are no longer there.

Comment: So you'll have to make sure that the data gets submitted to PHP, even if it's not the proper form, so PHP can fill in the fields' `value` when the form is regenerated. Or you use some Javascript to preserve the data, e.g. as a cookie or using localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post"> <div>Module1</div> <input type="text"
value="module1" name="module_id"> <input type="text" value="title 1"
name="title"> <input type="text" value="some text 1" name="text">
<input type="submit" name="form_1" value="submit"> </form>

<form method="post"> <div >Module2</div> <input type="text"
value="module2" name="module_id"> <input type="text" value="title 2"
name="title"> <input type="text" value="some text 2" name="text">
<input type="submit" name="form_2" value="submit"> </form>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['form_1'])){

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST); }

if(isset($_POST['form_2'])){

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST); } ?>
```

Comment: This one does basically what my code already does.  When you submit the 2nd form the 'echo' data from the first one goes away.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,you can do it.**

Eg :

```
// form1 on page a.php

<form method="post" action="a.php" name="form_one" >
<input type="text" name="form_1" value="if(isset($_POST['form_1'])) echo $_POST['form_1']; ?>" >
<input type="submit" name="submit_1" >
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
?> 
  <form method="post" action="a.php" name="form_two" >
  <input type="text" name="form_2" value="if(isset($_POST['form_2'])) echo $_POST['form_2']; ?>" >
   <input type="submit" name="submit_2" >
 </form>
<?php
 }
 ?>
```

**Now when you will submit `form_one` you will see `form_two` appear and the value in form one will stay intact in form_one and one the submitting form two the  value will remain.**

Hope it helped :)